# ElasticSearch aggregate nested fields as part of parent document

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have index with `Product` entities and nested `Variation` entities. `Product` entity consist of `Id`, `Title` and nested variations. `Variation` entity consist of `Color`, `Size` and `Price` fields. I need to aggregate search result by `Color`, `Size` and `Price` fields to get number of products for each color, size and price groups. If I use nested aggregation for these fields I get correct buckes but the number of documents in buckets is number of `Variation` entities per bucket. But I need to get number of `Product` entities (root documents) per bucket.

For example, the first product has variation (red, small, $10), (green, small, $10), (red, medium, $11) and the second product has variations (green, medium, $15). Nested aggregation returns 2 for `red` and 2 for `small` because 2 variations has `red` color and `small` size. But I need number of products (root entities) per bucket which should be 1 for `red` and 1 for `small`.

I also can't use children documents instead of nested documents because of other requirements.

How to compose the query to get this result?

Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "brand": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "variations": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "colour": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "size": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Variations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "variations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Colous": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "variations.colour"
          }
        },
        "Sizes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "variations.size"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Brands": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

The `Brand` aggregation works well because it gets number of root documents per group but nested aggregations return number of nested documents instead of number of root documents.

Comment: Can you include your mapping in your question as well as the query you're trying? That will help people recreate the problem and find solutions.

Comment: Sure. Added mapping and query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've tackled the problem the right way. Now you can simply use the [`reverse_nested` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) in order to "join back" to the root product and get the count of matching products for each for your variations.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Variations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "variations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Colous": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "variations.colour"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "product_count": {            <--- add this reverse nested agg
              "reverse_nested": {}
            }
          }
        },
        "Sizes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "variations.size"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "product_count": {            <--- add this reverse nested agg
              "reverse_nested": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Brands": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

In the response, you'll see that:

- 2 products are matching `colour: green`
- 1 product is matching `colour: red`
- 2 products are matching `size: medium`
- 1 product is matching `size: small`